# I have done something since 2018. (present perfect with SINCE)

Tags: tense

I have three sentences below. Does the first and second sentences mean this state of *being a member* or *living* continues up to now? I started to be a member of XXX Club in 2018, and now I am still a member of it. I started to live here in 2018, and I still live here now.

Is the third sentence different from the first and second? It could mean 1) I started to write poems in 2018, and now I still write poems, and 2) I wrote poems occasionally. I wrote two poems in 2018, and three poems in 2019. Now I don't write them.

Is this right?

> I have been a member of XXX Club since 2018.
>
> I have lived here since 2018.
>
> I have written poems since 2018.

Comment: In the present perfect with SINCE, how should I judge it's about a continual action or regular action or occasional action?

Comment: since **always** implies continuity.

Answer (score 0):

I have been a member of XXX Club since 2018.  - I joined (xxx club) in 2018 and continue to be a member.

I have lived here since 2018.  - I moved here in 2018 and have been (living) here ever since

I have written poems since 2018. - I started writing poetry in 2018 and still do.

(Sentence three does not specify how often you write poems but implies you do still continue to write poetry)

Comment: How about this sentence: I've read "Pride and Prejudice" since 2018. Does it mean I read it during a time between 2018 and present and I do not read it now?

Comment: Hi Stephen Lui, : I've read "Pride and Prejudice" means you have completed the book.  This would not be followed with since 2018 as to do so would imply you have not finished the book yet "I've read" is usually taken to mean you have

Comment: Hi Stephen Lui, : I've read "Pride and Prejudice" means you have completed the book.  This would not be followed with since 2018 as to do so would imply you have not finished the book yet "I've read" is usually taken to mean you have read the whole book.  If Pride and prejudice  were an ongoing magazine or say monthly journal publication then the statement "I've read "Pride and Prejudice" since 2018 would indeed mean you started reading the publication in 2018 and have been reading it ever since including the latest most recent magazine and you will be reading the next issue when it comes out.

Comment: Stephen : Now the best way to state your intention I believe would be to say :  I've been READING Pride and Prejudice since 2018.  This would imply you've started the book and have been working your way through ever since 2018 and you are still reading it i.e. have not finished the book.

Comment: This sentence "I've learnt how to swim since I moved to this city" means I have completed learning how to swim, and it is followed by "since".

Comment: I have been reading P&P since 2018.  I have been learning how to swim since 2018.  I finished P&P in 2018.  I learned how to swim in 2018.  Sticking with time these are all correct.  I've read P&P since 2018 is incorrect.  I've learned to swim since 2018 is incorrect.  I've learned to swim since moving to this city.  I've read P&P since moving to this city.  These are all correct.

Comment: Why is "I've learned to swim since 2018" incorrect, while "I've learned to swim since moving to this city" is correct?

Answer (score 0):

"Since" always means the action continues until the time of the main verb, from that time to the time we're talking about. So with present perfect, it means the action continues until now, because it's present.